# which php and php -v not the same

Tags: php, terminal

can anyone help me please ?
I am trying to see php version in my terminal and i don't know whats happening because I get an error that see:

> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.10/bin/php: No such file or directory

When I check which php, the returned PATH is:

> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh sorry I found the solution:

**~/.bash_profile**

> export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin:$PATH

**~/.profile**

> alias php='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.10/bin/php'

Answer (score 0):

You can also check PHP version by making a php file and write `echo phpinfo();` in it, and run the file in your browser.